# dividing big dataset python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

My dataset Features shape is (80102, 2592) and label.shape (80102, 2). I want to consider only few rows for traning as it is taking lot of time for training the CNN model. How can I divide the dataset in python and consider only few rows for traning and tesing both.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please share some of your code and explain your problems with it. Don't expect StackOverflow to write your code for you.

Comment: Sorry got it.. actually I am new to this area but I got the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in the form of arrays let X be the array containing the data and y be the array containing the labels. You can use sklearn train_test_split function to create new samples of the data per the code below

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
percent=.1 specify the percentof data you want to use, in this case 10%
X_data, X_dummy, y_labels, y_dummy=train_test_split(X,y,train_size=percent,randon_state=123, shuffle=True)
```

X_data will contain 10% of the original data and will be shuffled
y_labels will contain 10% of the corresponding labels.
If you want to specifically set the number of samples set train_size to an integer value. If you need further information the documentation is located [here.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) If you data is a pandas dataframe you can use the pandas function pandas.DataFrame.sample..Documentation for that is [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html). Assume your data frame is called data. The code below will produce a new data frame with a specified percent of the original rows

```
percent=.1
new_data=pandas.data.sample(n=None, frac=percent, replace=False, weights=None, random_state=123, axis=0)
```